# Outlook Email backup and restore

Tags: email, backup, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-office, restore

Is it possible to backup emails from one account and import them into another account?

I am moving from one host to another and I don't want to lost my emails.  I will still be using the same email account, it will just be located at a new location.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, just export it as a PST within Outlook. You can then import this when your new email account is set up.

Comment: This is what I thought but when I was doing that I was getting an error message.  It turns out I already had the archive open when I was trying to restore it.

Answer (score 2):

You can also grab your Outlook PST file from:

> C:\Documents and Settings\USERNAME\Local Settings\Application Data\Microsoft\Outlook

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you mean by account, another method might be to get an IMAP account. Since this type of account lets you access messages on a server, you could move your messages from outlook to this account, then move them back into whatever account you are using. This also lets you migrate between different programs and computers, but should be just as applicable to different accounts on the same computer as well.